# Doctrine2 OrderBy specific value

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Is Doctrine able to sort results by a specific value?

Ill try to do something like this..

```
$queryBuilder->addOrderBy($queryBuilder->expr()->eq('t0.ID',$ID));
$queryBuilder->addOrderBy('t0.ID');
```

To get something like this query would return.

```
select ID from test order by ID = '1234', ID;
```

Exception:

```
Syntax Error line 0 col 72: Error: Expected end of string got '='
```

I also tried to use FIND_IN_SET but this doesnt work, too.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 7):

You can add [Doctrine extension](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions) ([this](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle) if you're using Symfony) so you can use the MySql `IF` statement, then in your query you can:

```
$qb->addSelect('IF(t0.ID = 1234, 1, 0) AS HIDDEN mainSort')
```

then you can sort by it using

```
$qb->orderBy('mainSort', 'DESC');
```

**Update**

If you don't want to add Doctrine extensions, you can use the `CASE` statement which is regular SQL, this way:

```
$qb->addSelect('(CASE WHEN t0.ID = 1234 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS HIDDEN mainSort')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can not set values in an ORDER BY `order by ID = '1234'` this is normal for SQL. Instead use `SELECT ID FROM test WHERE ID = '1234' ORDER BY ID ASC`

In doctrine this would look like this:

```
$qb->select('t')
     ->from('Test t')
     ->where('t.id = :identifier')
     ->orderBy('t.id', 'ASC')
     ->setParameter('identifier', 1234);
```

Comment: Ok, i think i wasnt clear enough. I want all results so the where-part isnt necessary.Again, i want all results but the result should be in a specific order. I want all documents with the id = "1234" first and then alle other ids sorted by id. Is doctrine able to do this??

Comment: I don't even think SQL is able to do this, maybe with some heavy trickery. It's best if you do this after the results have been fetched.